A request to package authors
Not a question, but a comment aimed at package authors: Whenever you update your package, please include in the documentation at least some hint, or link to code in the package .sty file itself, that indicates what the changes are.
I frequently see some packages get updated (names omitted to protect the guilty) but the docs make no mention of what the changes or updates are in the latest version.

This has been the case for decades; it may have been related that in the distant past although the doc package which is often used by authors for their .dtx files has a \changes macro, some steps are needed to actually include the change list in the produced documentation and is anyhow of a limited usability. Some documentations use it well.  As a rule in LaTeX most developers are not keen indeed on clearly explaining when such or such change happened but I think the situation has improved.

sorry, but this is not a question and it does not belong here.
